# facebook friend status

Tags: iphone

how to get status update of user friends from facebook for iphone app

Comment: Please edit your question instead of posting the same again..  Poss Duplicate of : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4623971/facebook-friends-status

Answer (score 0):

Use the graph apis. Check this [link](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/user/), and there is a section called 'statutes'

Comment: i need friends status and i m trying to query the status table but not getting result