# facebook friends status

Tags: iphone

i am using this fql query but not getting status its showing null in status for getting facebook friends message please help

```
SELECT uid, pic_square, name, status FROM user WHERE uid IN (SELECT uid2 FROM friend WHERE uid1 = 100000660426865)
```

Answer (score 0):

The query you have built attempts to access your local host SQL server.

Would you like to get status from Facebook directly?
If so, you API provided by Facebook instead.

Comment: so whats the query or api please tell

Comment: He's using FQL which is a method of hitting the FB API using a SQL like language.